# Quadratic Transformations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a question about a quadratic transformation.  I need to write a function, $f(x)$, where $$g(x)=2f(x-5)+2$$ and $g(x) $ contains the points $(11,2)$ and $(3,2)$.  I think I know how to work backward with the points but I am stuck on writing the function.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
g(x)&=2f(x-5)+2\\
g(11)=2&=2f(11-5)+2\\
0&=f(6)\\
g(3)=2&=2f(3-5)+2\\
0&=f(-2)
\end{align}

So, $f(x)$ is a quadratic function that has zeroes at $-2$ and $6$, giving it some equation
\begin{align}
f(x)&=a(x+2)(x-6)=a(x^2-4x-12),\ a\in\mathbb{R}
\end{align}

There might be a mistake in the question that disallows us to find what the $a$ value is for $f(x)$, but if that is not the case, then you will find that $a$ can be any real value.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ then $$g(x) =2a(x-5)^2+2b(x-5)+2c+2 $$
So $$0= 36a+6b+c$$ and $$0 = 4a-2b+c$$

so $$32a+8b =0\implies b=-4a\implies c= -12a$$  So $$f(x)= a(x^2-4x-12)$$